# How to print asyncData request on pages‘ console in nuxt

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

I'm the new in Nuxt.js.
I want to see the request in asyncData just like networks in page console.
The console.log in axios.js will only print in the terminal。
Is there any good way?

Comment: It is? https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/#handling-errors